# TinyMCE does not insert line break for \n

Tags: jquery, tinymce

I have the following text

"3 stunning private villas.\n\n The Beach villa,  \n\nThe Cliff villa, "

showing this text in TinyMCE, Following is the TinyMCE js code

```
 tinyMCE.init({
    mode: "specific_textareas",
    element: editorID,
    encoding: "xml",
    content_css: hostURL + editorcssURL,
    editor_selector: editorClass,
    height: 500,
    external_plugins: { "nanospell": "nanospell/plugin.js" },
    nanospell_autostart: true,
    plugins: ["code searchreplace link print preview charmap paste advlist image textcolor"],
    default_link_target: isgConstants.DefaultTargetTypeForTinyMCEEditorLink,
    link_class_list: [
    { title: 'Special link', value: 'simple-link' },
    { title: 'None', value: '' }
    ],
    nanospell_server: "asp.net", // choose "php" "asp" "asp.net" or "java"
    spellchecker_languages: "English=en",
    relative_urls: false,
    style_formats: styleformat || "",
    toolbar: "cut copy paste | undo redo | bold italic underline strikethrough | bullist numlist outdent indent | charmap link image subscript superscript nanospell | print preview  code | styleselect | forecolor | backcolor | " + EditorCustomButtons,
    forced_root_block: "",
    menubar: "file edit insert format",
    statusbar: false,
    toolbar_items_size: 'medium',
    valid_elements: '*[*]',
    setup: function (event) {
      event.on('keyup', function (e) {
        isgProductText.GetCharCount(event, editorID);
      });
      event.on('init', function (e) {
        var text = tinyMCE.get(editorID).getContent({ format: 'text' });
        var numOfChar = text.trim().length;
        $.trim($('#noOfURChar').text(numOfChar));
      });
      //Add special link button - mk
      event.addButton('addclasstolink', {
        text: 'Special link to all',
        title: 'Add/Remove class to all',
        onclick: function () {
          var anchor = event.dom.select('a');

          var activeState = this.active();

          if (activeState) {
            $(anchor).removeClass('simple-link');
            this.active(false);
          }
          else {
            $(anchor).addClass('simple-link');
            this.active(true);
          }
        }
      });
    },
    file_browser_callback: function (field_name, url, type, win) {
      if (type == 'image') {
        $("#" + field_name).append('<input id="editorFileInpt" type="file">');
        $('#editorFileInpt').click();
        $('#editorFileInpt').change(function () { me.UploadTinyMceImage(field_name) });
      }
    }
  });
```

tinyMCE editor show "3 stunning private villas. The Beach villa, The Cliff villa," in a single line.

How can I allow line break where `\n` is present,

and also It doesn't show the space between ".\n\n The"

I have tried, but it doesn't work

```
    //force_p_newlines : false,
    //force_br_newlines : true,
    //convert_newlines_to_brs : false,
    //remove_linebreaks : false,
    //forced_root_block : false,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TinyMCE is an HTML editor and the `\n` character has no meaning in HTML.  If you want that to become a line break in TinyMCE you need to convert the `\n` to a `<br>` before you load the data into HTML.

If you give TinyMCE a text string with no wrapping HTML tags the entire string will be wrapped in a paragraph (`<p></p>`) to ensure that you have valid well-formed HTML.

Comment: How to do that in code ?

Answer (score -2):

of course, in html, \n is not show but in code mode de \n would appear...